# How do I Gzip a font for web banners?

Tags: fonts, gzip

I've been using Google Double Click Studio to create dynamic banner ads and **I'd like to use the client's custom font in all creative**. I've managed to do this by including the font file in the packaged creative (html, images, js etc) however it's adding significant file size to my banners which I want to avoid.

I found this article - http://www.phpied.com/gzip-your-font-face-files/ which says that font files can be Gzipped but it doesn't actually explain how to do it. I assume it has something to do with .htaccess settings? **Basically I just want to compress the font files (ttf, eot etc).**

Does anyone have any experience doing this for banner ads?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Ok, so I sort of figured out another solution. I downloaded an application called [Fontmin](http://ecomfe.github.io/fontmin/en) which is mainly used for minifying Chinese character fonts that can be up to 20mb. I managed to compress the font down from 61kb to 12kb which is small enough to be included with the source of my banner ads. Only trade off is I couldn't get [Fontmin](http://ecomfe.github.io/fontmin/en) working in Sierra but got it working in Yosemite (not sure about El Capitan).